# Remove RequiredFieldValidation from GridView Row

Tags: asp.net, gridview, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a Gridview like excel sheet.  I use it to update and insert new records.  The last row is used for insertion and can be empty.  I need to add RequiredFieldValidation for when rows are updated or inserted but I want to remove it when the whole row is empty.  How can this be implemented.

Thank you for your suggestions :)

Row1
[WithValdations]
Row N
[No Validations when Empty]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the validators are added with Id's you can reference those Id's from code, and turn the validators on and off programmatically.